# Как в boostrap 4 скрыть часть текста и показать её?

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

Как в boostrap 4 скрыть часть текста, а потом на кнопку показать скрытую часть.
Например у меня есть 30 слов, мне надо, что бы тока 10 из них было видно, а другие можно увидеть только, если нажмёшь на кнопку или сылку

Comment: поставьте вопрос конкретнее

Comment: Например у меня есть 30 слов, мне надо, что бы тока 10 из них было видно, а другие можно увидеть только, если нажмёшь на кнопку или сылку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите именно с помощью Bootstrap реализовать, то для этого в составе библиотеки есть компонент [Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/).

Сам бы я сделал через CSS+jQuery: `span display:none` + `$(...).show()`.